# Move file while running tomcat which is locking the file

Tags: java, file, tomcat, log4j

I am using log4j to log information in a text file during run time. This is a `log4j.properties` file found in the `tomcat/conf` folder

```
log4j.additivity.com.ixaris.apps.genericapp.web.filter.HttpAccessFilter=false

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy = org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern = C:/dev/generic-app/generic-app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Locking=false
```

This file is being saved correctly to the path I'm giving it. However when created, this file is instantly locked by tomcat itself. Later on, while tomcat is still running, I'm processing this log file information and I need to move this file to another folder: `C:/dev/generic-app/Processed`

I am using this code:

```
read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logFiles[i]));

//parse and upload records in file to db
parseLogFile(logFiles[i]);

//move files to processed folder
Files.move(logFiles[i].toPath(), new File(uploadedFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "\\\\" + logFiles[i].getName()).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

In parseLogFile I am making sure that I do `read.close()` to release any streams on the file.

This is however throwing this exception:

```
ERROR: Problem moving log files to Processed folder.
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\dev\generic-app\generic-app.2014-11-03.log -> C:\dev\generic-app\Processed\generic-app.2014-11-03.log: 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:286)
        at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1345)
        at log2db.Log2DB.main(Log2DB.java:90)
```

I also tried forcing Garbage Collection with `System.gc()` but no luck either.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If tomcat has a lock on the file there really isn't anything you can do...

Comment: yeah I'm trying to find a workaround here.. I'm assuming there is no direct solution.. and I'm not sure why tomcat is even locking the file even if I'm setting Locking to false

Comment: Why do you need to copy the files to 'Processed'?

Comment: Because these logs are being used for statistics and are being logged every day in a different file.. i need to seperate logs which have already been processed from logs which still have to be evaluated

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just in case anyone else comes looking for an answer here, you could check into a logrotate implementation for windows.  https://sourceforge.net/p/logrotatewin/wiki/LogRotate/

See the copytruncate option.

I have only used the Linux version, but so far that has been working fine for moving tomcat files for me.